# ALLBOT Arduino library

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

While installing the "ALLBOT" library, I ran into a problem. I tried to install the library via Arduino ide - it didn't work, I tried to download from GitHub - it doesn't work. Could you please help solve the problem.

```cpp
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows Store 1.8.57.0) (Windows 10)

sketch_jun03a:1:10: fatal error: ALLBOT.h: No such file or directory

 #include <ALLBOT.h>

          ^~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

exit status 1

ALLBOT.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

install the ALLBOT library from Tools->Manage Libraries from your arduino ide, here is guide https://docs.arduino.cc/software/ide-v1/tutorials/installing-libraries

[here i was able to to download and complie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys2xY.png)